# How to select certain table rows in TRichedit with Delphi (Xe10)

Tags: delphi, trichedit

i have a TjvRichedit control containing a table with some rows/cells filled with text.
I want to select some entire rows (eg. rows firstLine and firstLine+1) and copy them to clipboard (or to a stream). I use the code bellow :

```
SelStart := Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, firstLine, 0);
SelLength:= length(lines[firstLine]) + length(lines[firstLine+1]);
CopyToClipboard;
```

but it selects from firstLine to firstLine+3 (even selects rows from the next table !).
If i reduce the length (eg. SelLength:= 2) it selects two lines!
How can i do exactly what i want, please ?

Comment: What do you mean by **firstLine and firstLine+1)**? you mean the first line + first char from the second line?

Comment: I try it on Delphi 7 & Delphi 10 seattle & work fine.

Comment: You can see my updates & try it.

Comment: I tried your code but it has the same problem i faced with mine.
It happens when the document has **tables**  
It seems that counts some invisible characters (beyond the CR+LF of each line). So this is my problem. Witch and how many are they ?

Comment: I saw that the text of every table row with some cells is represented by a richEdit line. The text of such a line begins with characters #$FFF9#$D and ends with #$FFF9#$D.
The text between cells is divided by #7
The length(richedit.lines[i])  counts all those characters but the selstart and sellength doesn't (?). In this case how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the selection is at the beginning of a tablerow, you have to exclude the first two characters

```
RichEdit1.SelStart := Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, LineNo, 0) + 2; // start two chars beyond the linestart
RichEdit1.SelLength:= Perform(EM_LINELENGTH, RichEdit1.SelStart,0) - 2; // decrease the whole length by these two chars
```

The same in case of more than one lines (decrease the whole length only once by two)

Comment: That always select the two first chars from the first line.

Answer (score 1):

To select the first `Line` and copy the selected text to Clipboard:

```
RichEdit1.SelStart:=0;
RichEdit1.SelLength:=length(RichEdit1.Lines.[0]);
RichEdit1.CopyToClipboard;
```

To select the first `Line` + the first char from the second `Line` and copy the selected text to Clipboard :

```
RichEdit1.SelStart:=0;
RichEdit1.SelLength:=length(RichEdit1.Lines[0])+2;
RichEdit1.CopyToClipboard;
```

To select the second `Line` :

```
RichEdit1.SelStart:=length(RichEdit1.Lines[0])+1;
RichEdit1.SelLength:=length(RichEdit1.Lines[1]);
```